# Missing Return Statement in Java Recursive Function

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to generate a list of 25 non-repeating random numbers in Java, and I keep getting the Missing Return Statement error. As can be seen, I tried putting return before calling the method within itself. Not sure what's missing. It also didn't work with just the `return (rando)`

```
import java.util.*;
public class arrayList{

        ArrayList<Integer> checkRandom;
        ArrayList<Integer> array4;
        ArrayList<Integer> array2;
        ArrayList<Integer> array3;

    public  int addRandom(){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int b=0;
        for (int i=0; i<26; i++){
            int rando = rnd.nextInt(101);
            if (checkRandom.indexOf(rando) != -1){
                return addRandom();
            }
            else{
                checkRandom.add(rando);
                array4.add(rando);
                return (rando);
            }
        }
        for (int j=0;j<26;j++){
            int right;
            right = checkRandom.get(j);
            System.out.println(right);
        }
        return -1;
    }





    public static void main(String args[]){
        arrayList randomGen = new arrayList();
        randomGen.addRandom();
    }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at arrayList.addRandom(arrayList.java:14)
at arrayList.main(arrayList.java:37)
```

Comment: Why is `for (int i=0; i<26; i++){` in `addRandom`? **Hint** remove the loop. Also, ***please*** don't recreate `Random` in `addRandom`. That's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    while (list.size() < 25) {
      int index = rand.nextInt(101);

      if (!list.contains(index)) {
          list.add(index);
      }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use a much simpler method using Java 8 streams. For example, to create an array of 26 distinct random integers betweeen 0 and 100:

```
int[] randomArray = new Random().ints(0, 101).distinct().limit(26).toArray();
```

To explain in a bit more detail, this statement can be interpreted as: create a random number generator, use it to generate an endless stream of random numbers between 0 and 100, remove any duplicates, get the first 26 numbers in the stream and convert them to an `int` array.

Streams are incredibly powerful. Once your generator is in this form it's trivial to add a `sorted` operator or a `filter`, or to collect them into a `List` or `Map`.

Comment: This is pretty cool.  Can you explain this in detail?  Specifically the `...` at the end.

Comment: @MichaelQuatrani the ... was just a shorthand for 'and so on'. I'll update to something more specific and add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your method

```
public  int addRandom(){
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i=0; i<26; i++){
        int rando = rnd.nextInt(101);
        if (checkRandom.indexOf(rando) != -1){
            return addRandom();
        }
        else{
            checkRandom.add(rando);
            array4.add(rando);
            return (rando);
        }
    }
}
```

does not have a return statement at the end.  The method signature states you must return an integer.  The compiler does not know that the for statement will be executed until runtime.  Thus, you have to handle the case where the for loop is not executed.  Since you can tell it will be executed every time, adding a return -1; before the end of the method will solve your problem.

i.e.

```
public  int addRandom(){
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i=0; i<26; i++){
        int rando = rnd.nextInt(101);
        if (checkRandom.indexOf(rando) != -1){
            return addRandom();
        }
        else{
            checkRandom.add(rando);
            array4.add(rando);
            return (rando);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You can call the method by creating an instance of the class i.e.

```
arrayList randomGen = new arrayList();
randomGen.addRandom();
```

Btw, its standard in java to name your classes CamelCased.  i.e. ArrayList.  Although, you may want to rename it something else so you don't confuse your class with java.util.ArrayList (a popular java class)

Comment: How do I call the method from within the main, or anywhere from that matter? I'm getting the error that a non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a method local variable **b** inside your `addRandom` method and reassign it in your for loop finally return variable **b**.

```
    public  int addRandom(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int b=0;

    for (int i=0; i<26; i++){
        int rando = rnd.nextInt(101);
        if (checkRandom.indexOf(rando) != -1){
            b= addRandom();
        }
        else{
            checkRandom.add(rando);
            array4.add(rando);
            b=rando;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use recursion, you don't need loops. for example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Random rnd = new Random(); // do not create new Random object in each function call.

    final static int LIST_SIZE = 25;

    public void addRandom(List someList) {
        if (randomList.size() < LIST_SIZE) {
            int random = rnd.nextInt(101); // LIST_SIZE must be lesser than 101 otherwise you will got infinite recursion.
            if (!randomList.contains(random)) {
               randomList.add(random);
               someList.add(random);
            }
            addRandom(someList);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test();
        List<Integer> array4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        test.addRandom(array4);
        for (Integer value : array4) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```